# Remover infobar do Chrome ao executar testes com software automatizado

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Tentei implementar o `Chrome Options` em meu script para eliminar aquela barra amarela de informações do Chrome, que é exibida toda vez que estamos executando testes automatizados ("*Chrome is being controlled by automated test software*"), mas o resultado que tive foi a exibição de duas janelas do Chrome: uma minimizada, exibindo a infobar, e outra maximizada sem a exibição da infobar, onde meu script foi executado.

Por favor, saberiam me orientar onde estou errando? Já efetuei diversas modificações mas não consegui corrigir essa dupla abertura do navegador:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace navegador.PageObjects
{
    public class acessaSite
    {
    public IWebDriver driver;
        public acessaSite(IWebDriver driver)
        {
        this.driver = driver;
        }
        public void acessaURL()
        {

         var options = new ChromeOptions();
         options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
         options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
         options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
         driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://meusite.com.br");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Grata!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questão resolvida! O código final ficou:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Login
{
IWebDriver driver = null;
public capturaImagem tiraScreenshot;
public acessaSite navegador;
public LoginPositivo testePositivo;
public LoginNegativo testeNegativo;
public sair sessao;

    public Login()
    {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
    options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    tiraScreenshot = new capturaImagem(driver);
    navegador = new acessaSite(driver);
    testePositivo = new LoginPositivo(driver);
    testeNegativo = new LoginNegativo(driver);
    sessao = new sair(driver);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void DepoisDosTestes()
    {
    driver.Close();
    }

    [Test]
    public void AutomacaoLogin()
    {
    navegador.acessaURL();
    testePositivo.UsuarioSenhaValidos();
    sessao.FazLogoff();
    testeNegativo.CamposEmBranco();
    testeNegativo.UsuarioInvalido();
    testeNegativo.SenhaInvalida();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class acessaSite
{
public IWebDriver driver;
public capturaImagem tiraScreenshot;

    public acessaSite(IWebDriver driver)
    {
    tiraScreenshot = new capturaImagem(driver);
    this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void acessaURL()
    {
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.meusite.com.br");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    tiraScreenshot.salvaImagem();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Oi, tente instanciar opções do Chrome da seguinte forma:

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Esse é um caso em que você deve usar o tipo de variável explicitamente, para passar a intenção correta para a variável *driver*.

**Estou colocando essa parte para exemplificar melhor o que eu te respondi abaixo, tente ver se funciona dessa forma:**

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
    options.AddArguments("start-maximized"); //Isso deve iniciar o chrome maximizado
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
    options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    //driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://meusite.com.br");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Oi Bruno, obrigada pela dica, mas mesmo usando explicitamente ainda não funcionou... só o fato de instanciar o ChromeOptions, o código já se perde: 
`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Comment: Debugando percebi que a segunda janela está sendo aberta ao executar ` driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();`

Comment: Oi Carol, eu não consegui reproduzir esse cenário aqui, mas o que você fazer é trocar o comando de maximizar pelo seguinte argumento  `options.AddArguments("start-maximized");`

Comment: Bruno, mesmo alterando este trecho, o script se perde e abre a outra janela ao chamar o driver: `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.meusite.com.br");`. Existe algum argumento ou algo do tipo para acessar URL? Procurei na internet mas não encontrei.

Comment: @CarolCiola, não tinho visto, mas o constructor que você criou chamado "acessaSite" também chama o _driver_, por isso eu acho que quando o _driver_ é chamado ele acaba abrindo dois navegadores.

Comment: Bruno, consegui resolver a questão. Esta classe possui um constructor pois é chamada por uma classe principal. Então o correto seria eu incrementar o script da classe principal com o ChromeOptions, e não esta classe do exemplo. A classe principal instanciava o driver, e quando chamava esta classe do exemplo, o driver vindo da principal era "jogado fora" e um outro sem quaisquer propriedades era aberto.